# A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type System.Globalization.CultureInfo

Tags: c#, jquery, web-services, json

I'm using jquery to call a webservice which returns a dataset with a couple of tables in it.

This was working ok until i needed to set up my webmethod to accept a parameter. I reflected this on the client side with

```
data: "{paramname:'" + paramval+ "'}",
```

I now get the following error when the webmethod returns. This happens regardless of whats being returned in the dataset

> Error:{"Message":"A circular reference was detected while serializing
>   an object of type
>   \u0027System.Globalization.CultureInfo\u0027.","StackTrace":"   at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat)\r\n   at ...etc

When the webmethod has no parameters the client side js looks the same as below except the data: line is removed.

```
function ClientWebService(paramval){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "WebService1.asmx/webmethodName", 
    data: "{paramname:'" + paramval+ "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
        ParseResult(msg.d);
    },
    error: function(err) {
        if (err.status == 200) {
              ParseResult(err);
        }
        else { alert('Error:' + err.responseText + '  Status: ' + err.status); }
    }
});
```

}

Edit: As per suggestion to change the request to

```
data: {paramname: paramval},
```

yields the following error.

> Error:{"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: paramval.","StackTrace":"
>   at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32
>   depth)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String
>   input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer
>   serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String
>   input)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParamsFromPostRequest(HttpContext
>   context, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData
>   methodData, HttpContext context)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext
>   context, WebServiceMethodData
>   methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException"}  Status: 500

Comment: Just to note, you are right to send the json data as a string (vs actual json). You could try rephrasing the question to how to resolve the error:

"A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type System.Globalization.CultureInfo"

(which is what is happening at the server)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I changed my webmethod to return

```
ds.GetXml();
```

and this worked. Considering datasets are serializeable I'm not sure why I have to do this, but it gets me over this hurdle.

Comment: Please could you explain more on how you changed you webmethod?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem,

I removed Virtual keyword from my Entities which make lazy loading of object.

The problem solved!!

Answer (score 1):

this will often happen when serializing objects with entityrefs and entitysets. 
e.g if you have a set like this

```
public EntitySet<ProductCategory> Subcategories
```

the serializer will go into the `ProductCategory` and try to serialize all sets there aswell, often ending up back on the original object, and therefore creating a loop.

The best way to avoid this is to put  `[ScriptIgnore]` and `[NonSerialized]` on fields and `[ScriptIgnore]` on properties like this.

```
[ScriptIgnore]
[NonSerialized]
private EntitySet < ProductCategory > _Subcategories;
[ScriptIgnore]
[Association(Storage = "_Subcategories", ThisKey = "ID", OtherKey = "ParentID")]
public EntitySet < ProductCategory > Subcategories {
 get {
  return this._Subcategories;
 }
 set {
  this._Subcategories.Assign(value);
 }
}
```

Same on Refs

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been answered but I came across the same problem and thought I should put what worked for me here so others can hopefully tackle the problem.

```
data: JSON.stringify(Params),
```

By using the **JSON.stringify** method I got the required result

where **params** is equal to `{"key":"value"}`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this response when there was an type conversion exception server side.