# Returning DataSet from WebService and populating a datalist using jQuery $.ajax

Tags: asp.net, jquery, webmethod

Is there any way so that I can populate datalist from the returned DataSet from web service. I want to use $.ajax jquery function.
If yes, then please give me a small example.

Comment: See the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Beyond the documentation as noted above, do you have a specific question or feature that challenges you?

Answer (score 3):

This question is kind of old... but I'll answer anyway.

I would recommend using a custom class, but it *is* possible to do it using DataSets.

jQuery Code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Default.aspx/GetSomeData",
      data: "{}",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "xml",
      success: function (msg) {
        $(msg).find('Table').each(function (i, row) {
          alert($(row).find('Field').text());
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
```

C# Code:

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
    public static string GetSomeData()
    {
        var dataSet = new DataSet();

        // Use proper try-catch!
        string connStr = "Connection String Here";
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            using (var com = new SqlCommand("select top 5 ID, Field from Table", conn))
            {
                var adp = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
                adp.Fill(dataSet);
            }
        }

        return dataSet.GetXml();
    }
```

**Note:** I used the DataSet.GetXml method because the resulting XML is simpler and because you may get some [weird errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673079/a-circular-reference-was-detected-while-serializing-an-object-of-type-system-glo) just returning the DataSet as is.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it. You must create your custom class with simple types and return it.